# SP2010: Can I show in a column of my item the parent folder name?

Tags: folder

I am using sp2010. I have a document library. In this library we have many folders. Inside these folders we have items. When I see the list of items in a folder I would like to have a column with the parent folder name. Is this possible?

Comment: What would be your end goal? Are you using this as a list view wp? Just wondering because you can see the parent folder name in the breadcrumb

Answer (score 0):

No OOTB way but You can add a column on the document library and populate it with the document parent folder name using Event handler ItemAdding / ItemAdded event.

Here is method how to create event handler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx
http://sharepoint.madhurchadha.com/tag/itemadded-event-handler-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: what about a sharepoint designer workflow which is triggered by each new created item?

Comment: you can do it that way as well.one of my old project a developer use the above method that's why I mentioned that.